# Prove uniform equicontinuity and boundness

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, equicontinuity

Suppose
$K = \{x(t) \in C[a,b], \forall x \  x(t) = 0 \ has \ a \ solution \}$.

Prove that $K$ is uniformly bounded and uniformly equicontinuous.

Could anyone spare a hint on how to use the fact every function in the set has at least one root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, the set $K$ is **not** uniformly bounded or equicontinuous.

Consider the family $x_n \in C[a,b]$ defined by $$x_n(t) = n\left(t - \tfrac{a+b}2 \right), \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, t \in [a,b].$$ These are just increasingly steep linear functions which are zero at the midpoint $t = \frac{a+b}2$. The maximum then occurs at $t =a$ or $t = b$ , and has a value $$\lvert x_n(a)\rvert = \lvert x_n(b) \rvert = \frac{n(b-a)}{2}$$ which is unbounded as $n$ gets large. Therefore $K$ is not uniformly bounded. Likewise, since each function $x_n$ has increasingly large slope, the family is not equicontinuous.

Comment: Very interesting, I guess I was tunnel visioned on trying to prove the fact that it is uniformly bounded or equicontinuous since thats how the question was formulated.
Should've been more careful in exploring possibilities, thank you for the help sir!